# Applying a functor to a homotopy of chain maps yields an isomorphism of homology groups?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I'm reading through the section on derived functors in Lang's Algebra and I came across this explanation of the natural isomorphism $H^i(F(I_M)) = H^i(F(J_M))$ for two different injective resolutions $0\rightarrow M\rightarrow I_M$ and $0\rightarrow M\rightarrow J_M$:

> Given an object $M$, let
>   $$
>   0 \to M \to I^0 \to I^1 \to I^2 \to
> $$
>   be an injective resolution, which we abbreviate by
>   $$
>   0 \to M \to I_M,
> $$
>   where $I_M$ is the complex $I^0 \to I^1 \to I^2 \to$.
>   We let $I$ be the complex
>   $$
>   0 \to I^0 \to I^1 \to I^2 \to
> $$
>   We define the **right-derived functor** $R^n F$ by
>   $$
>     R^n F(M)
>   = H^n(F(I)),
> $$
>   in other words, the $n$-th homology of the complex
>   $$
>   0 \to F(I^0) \to F(I^1) \to F(I^2) \to
> $$
>   Directly from the definitions and the monomorphism $M \to I^0$, we see that there is an isomorphism
>   $$
>   R^0F(M) = F(M).
> $$
>   This isomorphism seems at first to depend on the injective resolution, and so do the functors $R^n F(M)$ for other $n$.
>   However, from Lemmas 5.1 and 5.2 we see that given two injective resolutions of $M$, there is a homomorphism between them, and that any two homomorphisms are homotopic.
>   **If we apply the functor $F$ to these homomorphisms and to the homotopy, then we see that the homology of the complex $F(I)$ is in fact determined up to unique isomorphism.**
>   One therefore omits the resolution from the notation and from the language.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQeCq.png).)

The two lemmas mentioned are as follows:

> **Lemma 5.1**
>   If $f, g$ are homotopic, then $f, g$ induce the same homomorphism on the homology $H(E)$, that is
>   $$
>          H(f_n)
>   =      H(g_n)
>   \colon H^n(E)
>   \to    H^n(E').
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY1LY.png).)
>
> **Lemma 5.2**
>   Consider two complexes:
>   $$
>   \require{AMScd}
>   \begin{CD}
>     0
>     @>>>
>     M
>     @>>>
>     E^0
>     @>>>
>     E^1
>     @>>>
>     E^2
>     @>>>
>     \cdots
>   \\
>     {}
>     @V \varphi VV
>     {}
>     {}
>     {}
>     {}
>   \\
>     0
>     @>>>
>     M'
>     @>>>
>     I^0
>     @>>>
>     I^1
>     @>>>
>     I^2
>     @>>>
>     \cdots
>   \end{CD}
> $$
>   Suppose that the top row is exact, and that each $I^n$ ($n \geq 0$) is injective.
>   Let $\varphi \colon M \to M'$ be a given homomorphism.
>   Then there exists a morphism $f$ of complexes such that $f_{-1} = \varphi$;
>   any any two such are homotopic.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/civKp.png).)

I don't really understand this proof sketch—I can't see where the natural isomorphism of functors comes from.

EDIT: $F$ is a left exact functor between abelian categories.

Comment: The highlighted area is not about $R^0F = F$, it's about the fact that $R^nF$ does not depend on the injective resolution. That $R^0F =F$ follows from the fact that $F$ is left exact

Comment: I just realised what I asked made no sense at the exact time of your comment, I will take a moment to change the question!

Comment: I completely rephrased my question - would you happen to have any input?

Comment: You need $F$ to be left exact for $R^0F(M)\simeq F(M)$ to hold.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I'm sorry that I never mentioned it in the question - this is the case in my scenario.

Comment: The isomorphism between the $H^*(F(I_M))$ and $H^*(F(J_M))$ comes from a "standard" trick with universal properties. Consider a diagram like in Lemma 5.2 with three rows. $I$ on top, $J$ in the middle, $I$ at the bottom again. $\phi=id_M$ all the way. Because $I$ and $J$ are resolutions they are both exact and injective, so the Lemma applies to both parts AS WELL AS TO THE DIAGRAM WHERE WE LEAVE OUT THE $J$-ROW ALTOGETHER.

Comment: (cont'd) Lemma 5.2. applied to the two parts gives the existence of matching morphisms of complexes $f:I\to J$ and $f':J\to I$. Because the diagram commutes, their composition $f'\circ f:I\to I$ matches the identity $\phi=id_M$. But, $id_I$ is another such morphism of complexes. By the unique (up to homotopy) part of Lemma 5.2. we get that $f$ and $f'$ satisfy $H^*(f'\circ f)=H^*(id)=id$. Swap the roles of of $I$ and $J$ to get that the other composition must also be the identity at the leve of (co)homology.

Comment: Forgot to add the conclusion that $H^*(F(f))$ and $H^*(F(f'))$ will then be isomorphisms between $H^*(F(I))$ and $H^*(F(J))$. Sorry about that.

Comment: Don't be sorry - I definitely caught on after a few lines! This was exactly the explanation I was in dire need of! Feel free to copy it into an answer and I can give you the bountiful internet points that you deserve :)

Comment: So, to finish the conclusion, would the following argument be correct?
Applying $F$ extends the homotopy $f\circ f'\sim id_I$ to a homotopy $F(f\circ f')\sim F(id_I)$, and since F is a functor, $F(f\circ f')=Ff\circ Ff'$ and $F(id_I)=id_{FI}$. Then there is a homotopy $Ff\circ Ff'\sim id_{FI}$, so we have that $H^*(Ff\circ Ff')=H^*(id_{FI})$, but since $H^*$ is also a well known functor, $H^*(Ff\circ Ff')=H^*(Ff)\circ H^*(Ff')$ and $H^*(id_{FI})=id_{H^*(FI)}$. So $H^*(Ff)$ is a left inverse to $H^*(Ff')$. Then repeat the argument to show right inverse?

Comment: Correct. It's been a while since I did anything related to homological algebra, so I'm a bit rusty. At work now, so feel free to post that as an answer. At the moment I am a bit reluctant to recall how to make commutative diagrams with MathJax/LaTeX, so that might take too long :-)

Comment: I understand - thanks again!